# How do I join seamlessly two identical components?

Tags: modeling, topology

Scenario in the pictures. I've been trying to join the four selected faces into one long rod, but I fail to do so seamlessly. I tried to (F)ill the faces and merge the vertices, but it creates other unconnected edges that mess up the shading and everything.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use right click (*Context* menu) > *Bridge Faces*. It will automatically delete the inner faces.

Comment: Wait, what does W do? For me it enables Circle select.

Comment: Sorry, W was for 2.79, it looks like it's right click for 2.8